# How to convert this json to text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My Code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'shop')) {
      const shop = LabyMod.getShop('all').then(shop => shop.map((sh) => sh.name));
      const awaitShop = await shop

      console.log(JSON.stringify(awaitShop))
    }
```

What I get:

```json
[ 'Waveover', 'Frightening', 'Eagle' ]
```

What I want (as text):

```
Waveover
Frightening
Eagle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that helped solve my question. The code sample I used is below:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'shop')) {
    const shop = await LabyMod.getShop('all')
    const shopNames = shop.map(sh => sh.name);
    console.log(shopNames.join('\n'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function and add a new line with `\n`

E.g.:

```js
console.log(awaitShop.join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`awaitShop` is already a javascript array. You can use a javascript array join to join this array, putting a newline character (`\n`) between each entry:

```js
console.log(awaitShop.join('\n'));
```

This will return you a String containing newline characters

```js
"Waveover
Frightening
Eagle"
```